# How to call controller once for modal dialog?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui

Here's [a plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/V5krTZ?p=preview/) demonstrating my problem(you have to open up console). How to try it?

1. Click show modal 2x times.
2. click Notification button. Then in the console, there is:

   `Notification broadcasted. example.js:44
   2 Notification received.`

Which means the notification is received twice. That is because the controller for the modal is called on each open(). My problem is, that I just want it to be called once for the modal. I know that $on() return unregister function, but in my app I have quite a few events registered and I don't want to be unregistering them each time modal is closed. I also cannot have $on() anywhere else, because I need to work with dialog itself. Isn't there some easier way of ensuring, that for each modal dialog, I have the $scope events registered only once?

Comment: Change the title so it will reflect your question..

Comment: Sorry,I absolutely forgot about the title since I wrote some mumbo jumbo there at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

The plnkr doesn't work (currently), and a smaller plnkr showing just the issue would be better.

In your open() and close() functions in ModalDemoCtrl, how about toggling a $scope property (e.g., $scope.showModal) that tracks the state of your modal.  When it is already open, don't call modelService() again.